# Sambashare permission issues and chgrp

Tags: samba, nas

Very very new to Ubuntu here and learning as I go by setting up a NAS.

I'm having an issue with Sambashare where I'm losing permissions in every subfolder aside from the root folder while accessing the NAS from my windows desktop. Can't write at all in any subfolder. BUT I am able to correct this issue (seems to be temporary, but I haven't tested too much) with:

```
sudo chgrp sambashare /mediaserver/data/directory
```

But this only works in the directory I've specified and not any parent/child directories.

My SMB config looks like this:

```
[NAS]
path = /mediaserver
guest ok = No
writeable = Yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the procedure I followed to setup Samba:

```
# Update device:
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y

# Install Samba
sudo apt-get install samba samba-common-bin
Y

# identify the drive
sudo fdisk -l

# Note the partition ie.: /dev/sda1

# Create directory to share 
sudo su
cd /
mkdir mediaserver
ls -l

# Provide user full access to the directory
chmod 777 mediaserver

- Alt + D to exit root mode

# To configure Samba share:
sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf


# Insert new section at bottom of conf
[NAS]
path = /mediaserver 
writeable = Yes 
create mask = 0777 
directory mask = 0777 


# Restart the Samba daemon after making changes
sudo systemctl restart smbd

# Mount ext drive to the share directory
sudo mount -t auto /dev/sda1 /mediaserver

# Enable ext drive to be auto mounted whenever system reboots
sudo nano /etc/fstab

# Add the following line:
/dev/sda1 /mediaserver auto noatime 0 0

# Set group ownership of mediaserver directory to sambashare group
sudo chgrp sambashare /mediaserver

# Add user account to sambashare
sudo smb passwd -a authuser1

# To find systems IP address:
ifconfig

# On Windows map network drive:
\\1.2.3.4\NAS
```

Comment: I've update my response based on your edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach to the share definition may work better:

Make sure the shared folder has sambashare as group:

```
sudo chown :sambashare /mediaserver
```

Add the setgid bit to the shared folder:

```
sudo chmod 2775 /mediaserver
```

*The setgid bit will force every new file/folder to have the group equal to samnbashare in this case.*

Then change the share definition to this:

```
[NAS]
path = /mediaserver
guest ok = No
writeable = Yes
force group = sambashare
create mask = 0777
force directory mode = 2777
```

And restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

**EDIT: Based on your original post edit:**

```
# Add user account to sambashare
sudo smb passwd -a authuser1
```

No you did not. What you did is add that user ( and it's smbpasswd not smb passwd ) to the samba password database.

You need to add your user to the sambashare group:

```
sudo gpasswd -a authuser1 sambashare
```

That user needs to logoff and log back in again for group membership to be updated.

Not a big fan of mounting partitions with /dev/sda1 either since we've all moved on to using UUID's or LABELS.

The output of `lsblk -f` will provide you with that information if you want to reset your fstab declaration.

Comment: Went ahead and tried this but still have permission issues. Where can I look next to troubleshoot? For reference, [I followed this video on how to setup Samba.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kORPl14tkWg)

Comment: I'm not going to watch a video to see how you set up samba. It's a generational thing I guess. Note that my proposal relates to all new files / folders added by the client. It doesn't do anything with any files already present.

Comment: Fair enough. I can write out my process if it would help point out an issue in my setup. Do you have any suggestion to modify the permissions of folders/files already in my share?

Comment: I added the Samba install process I followed to my OP for reference.